# pytest in VS Code: Point out test failures because of NotImplementedError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, tdd

I am using pytest and Visual Studio Code for test-driven development of a Python library.

Many functions have been drafted as stubs but not yet implemented, so they raise a `NotImplementedError`. Likewise, development starts from failing tests.

Now I would like to have a better overview of why tests are failing - `NotImplementedError` or an "actual" exception. Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Is VS really that relevant here? Wouldn't it be better to create a short example that illustrates the issue (and can actually be run) instead of embedding a partial (but nevertheless redundant) screenshot?

Comment: and then you get the false impression your program is tested and working, now you have the feedback of which test function you have to look at, In TDD you write a failing test, implement to behavior till test passes, **THEN** go to the next test

Comment: @rioV8 I understand your argument. It's not such a great thing to have lots of failing tests (or lots of placeholders). On the other hand, testing with the `xfail` mark (see my answer) shows the *xfailed* tests neither in red nor in green. So you get a ternary result instead of a binary one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to [mark tests as *expected to fail*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/skipping.html#xfail-mark-test-functions-as-expected-to-fail), so something like this will help distinguish `NotImplementedError`s from test actually failing:

```
import pytest

def func(x):
    return x + 1

def func_var(x):
    raise NotImplementedError

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=NotImplementedError)
def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=NotImplementedError)
def test_answer_var():
    assert func_var(3) == 4
```

I cannot tell you how it looks in VS, but the console edition is already promising:

```
$> pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\Projects\Eigene\pytest
plugins: Faker-13.3.5
collected 2 items

test_first.py Fx                                                         [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_answer _________________________________

    @pytest.mark.xfail(raises=NotImplementedError)
    def test_answer():
>       assert func(3) == 5
E       assert 4 == 5
E        +  where 4 = func(3)

test_first.py:11: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED test_first.py::test_answer - assert 4 == 5
======================== 1 failed, 1 xfailed in 0.14s =========================
```

Comment: I have been looking at xfail too. However, VS Code shows it as just another passing test, so it does not serve the purpose. I think xfail is meant for testing that the correct exception gets raised. There is a difference between a method that should stay unimplemented (expected to raise NotImplementedError) and a placeholder.

Comment: You say *I think xfail is meant for testing that the correct exception gets raised.* -- I think that this is not quite right, the docs state: *This test will run but no traceback will be reported when it fails. Instead, terminal reporting will list it in the “expected to fail” (XFAIL) […]*. So *x* stands for *expected*.